# Understanding rails layout behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `FooController` and a `foo.html.erb` in layouts.

So I expect that when I go to `localhost:3000/foo/some_action`, I will be shown the **foo layout**.

But that is NOT the case. I get a **blank page**. Only if I put `def index` in the controller AND `index.html.erb` the layout renders.

Why is that behaviour in Rails?

Comment: may also help to know how you defined the route

Comment: Check this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Are you running in production mode? You shouldn't get a blank response in a browser in development mode -- there should be an explanation instead.

Answer (score 1):

Layouts are intended to wrap around a view (or other rendered content); without anything to wrap, the layout is consequently not useful.